# Generating an object's absolute url without html markup

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a method like "full_url" such that @comment.full_url or full_url_for(@comment) returns "http://www.host.com/comments/id" where www.host.com is the default host domain and id is @comment.id.  Or, if not, what would be an elegant way to generate this url string?

I'm pretty new at Rails, most of the methods I've learned insert the  tag and other markup.

[url_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for) is not helping because I can't do something like the following:

```
url_for(@comment, {:only_path => false})
```

I've spent way too much time trying to figure this out.  It came down to either hacking or asking for the right way on SO.  Here I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are setting up your routes correctly in your `config/routes.rb` file then you should have access to named routes in your controller and in your views. Which should mean that all you should need to do is:

```
comment_path(@comment)
```

Or for the full url

```
comment_url(@comment)
```

To see a list of all of the routes from the command line, you can type `rake routes` from the project root. Welcome to rails! Here is a good resource for rails 3 routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

some additional resources via Railscasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/231-routing-walkthrough

http://railscasts.com/episodes/232-routing-walkthrough-part-2

Comment: Thanks Geoff.  I do need a more fundamental understanding of routing.. bookmarked the routing guide.

Comment: I went ahead and added some more links to some Railscasts episodes that would be good to get you going. I recommend going through that site, it is a wonderful resource for most things pertaining to rails.